# What is the difference between Do you arrive vs Are you arriving

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple, future-time

I would like to know what is the difference between these two examples and can I use them both with the same meaning?

1. When do you arrive tomorrow?
2. When are you arriving tomorrow?

Comment: For all practical purposes, they're equivalent. Both are colloquial English, though,grammatically, the first elides "plan to" or "expect to", i.e., "When do you expect to arrive tomorrow?" The second *is* grammatically correct, though.

Comment: Don't answer in comments

Answer (score 1):

[1] we use the present simple to refer to events in the future if there is a clear schedule.

> *"When do you arrive tomorrow?"*  (Here, your arriving tomorrow is scheduled.)

[2] We use the present continuous to indicate **"a fixed plan"** in near future :

> *"When are you arriving tomorrow?"*

Comment: I don't understand it yet!

Comment: Use simple present for a scheduled action in future. Use present continuous for a fixed plan in near future.

Comment: @AbuOmar Think of this usage as: Are you scheduled to arrive tomorrow.